# How do I split a string to be placed in multiple textboxes?

Tags: c#, string, split

What I am trying to do is split a string, depending on its length, so I can assign certain sections of it, to different textboxes.

```
if (str.Length <= 2)
{
    textbox1.Text = str; //(the first textbox is 2 characters long, so this is fine)
}
else if() //this is where I need to split the first two characters 
          //into the first textbox, then the next 2 into a second 
          //textbox, than anything left over into the third textbox
```

Say the value of the string is 123456789, I would want 89 in the first box, 67 in the second, and 12345 in the third, if that makes sense.

Comment: I guess you count from the right? "...123456789, I would want 89 in the first box, 67 in the second, and 12345 in the third..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
string theString = "123456789";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^(.+?)(.{1,2}?)?(.{1,2})$");
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = re.Match(theString)

this.TextBox1.Text = m.Groups[3].Value
this.TextBox2.Text = m.Groups[2].Value
this.TextBox3.Text = m.Groups[1].Value
```

Edit: Oh, you're going backwards. Fixed.

Edit 2: I'm sick of `Substring` and math :)

Comment: I'm confused as to how this goes backwards. 
Substring(6, 4) would go backwards? Is basically what I'm getting out of this.

Comment: So, problem

BSilver.Text = BuyS.Length > 2 ? BuyS.Substring(BuyS.Length - Math.Min(2, BuyS.Length - 2), Math.Min(2, BuyS.Length - 2)) : string.Empty;

Is returning the same thing as the first value. Say 121314, the first and second box are saying 14

Comment: Fixed, the first (2, theString.Length - 2) in the second line needed to be (4, theString.Length - 2)

Comment: @Chillu: I'm kind of sick of `Substring` and that annoying long math for now, so I've just edited  to include a much clearer regular expression. (Maybe `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` would help)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx):

```
"123456789".Substring(0, 2);    => "12"
"123456789".Substring(2, 2);    => "34"
"123456789".Substring(4);       => "56789"
```

Comment: The only problem with this, is that it starts from the beggining and not the end, I would need to do the opposite. I can, and probably will end up using this unless there is a way to do what you did, but starting from the opposite end.

Comment: this would work if you just reverse the string first, then reverse em back.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the LinqPad Working Code:

```
void Main()
{
    string theString = "123456789";

    theString.Substring(theString.Length - 2, 2).Dump();
    theString.Substring(theString.Length - 4, 2).Dump();
    theString.Substring(0, theString.Length - 4).Dump();
}
```